# Multiple fetchs in generator function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, asynchronous, fetch

as I'm trying to learn how to use generator functions, I've run into a problem using it to run multiple fetchs.

**What I'm trying to do:**
I'm trying to use the Hackernews API to fetch a newsstory, and then afterwards, fetching a comment from the same API, using the id given in the response.

**Output:**
*{ value: Promise {  }, done: false }

TypeError: Cannot read property 'kids' of undefined
    at getFirstComment (C:\Users\madsn\Documents\dev\generatorfunctions\fetchingInterTwice.js:13:29)
    at getFirstComment.next ()
    at runThroughIt (C:\Users\madsn\Documents\dev\generatorfunctions\fetchingInterTwice.js:31:35)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

{ value: undefined, done: true }

{ value: undefined, done: true }*

**Code:**

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")


function requestStuff(url) { ///simple request
    return fetch(url).then(respJson => respJson.json()).catch(err => console.log(err));
}

function* getFirstComment() {
    try {

        //gets the story and the comments id(kids of type array)
        var result1 = yield requestStuff("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/8863.json?print=pretty")
        var resID = result1.kids[0];

        //gets the comment-text given the comment-id
        var result2 = yield requestStuff("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/" + resID + ".json?print=pretty")
        var resText = result2.text

        console.log(resText.text)

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

let main = getFirstComment()

async function runThroughIt(generator) {
    let stepOne = await generator.next()
    console.log(stepOne)
    let stepTwo = await generator.next()
    console.log(stepTwo)
    let stepThree = await generator.next()
    console.log(stepThree)

}

runThroughIt(main)
```

Thanks in advance if you have a fix or the link to an article explaining this!

Comment: `requestStuff()` is asynchronous and returns a promise not the data. `yield` is not a substitute for `await`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the issues with your code:

Your `requestStuff` function should be `async` and the return value should be the evaluated result from the network request. Currently, you're simply returning the promise object.

The  `yield` keyword will "kick" you out of the function **BEFORE** the result from the fetch expression is assigned to `result1`.

Here is how you could fix it:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")


async function requestStuff(url) { ///simple request
    const res = await fetch(url)
      .then(respJson => respJson.json())
      .catch(err => console.log(err));

  return res;

}

async function* getFirstComment() {
    try {

        //gets the story and the comments id(kids of type array)
        var result1 = await requestStuff("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/8863.json?print=pretty");

      yield result1;

      var resID = result1.kids[0];


        //gets the comment-text given the comment-id
        var result2 = await requestStuff("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/" + resID + ".json?print=pretty")
        var resText = result2.text

        console.log(resText.text)

      yield resText;

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

let main = getFirstComment()

async function runThroughIt(generator) {
    let stepOne = await generator.next();
    console.log("res from step 1! ", stepOne);
    let stepTwo = await generator.next()
    console.log("res from step 2: ", stepTwo);

  //will return undefined because the function has finished evaluating!
    let stepThree = await generator.next()
    console.log(stepThree)

}

runThroughIt(main)
```

The above works! 
Now pay special attention to where the `yield`, `await` and `async` keywords are being called in my example and compare it with where you called it in your code!